# Passing a path to a variable

Tags: python, git, kivy

I tried:

```
kivy="c:\...\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32"
```

and

```
kivy = /c/.../Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32
```

How would someone add a path into a new created variable in Git Bash?

or add

```
source /c/.../Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32/kivyenv.sh
```

or

```
cd /c/.../Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32
```

What would the code look like.

Thank you

Comment: What are you even working in? "Git Bash"? Is that [this thing](https://openhatch.org/missions/windows-setup/install-git-bash)? What are you trying to do? "add a path into a new created variable" is not an easy description to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslash as follows

```
$ kivy="C:\\folder\\filename"
$ echo $kivy
C:\folder\filename
```